# Making an alias for \xskakcomment in xskak package

Tags: macros, chess, xskak

I'm trying to make an alias for \xskakcomment to save typing.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}

\let\skakcom=\xskakcomment

\begin{document}

\newchessgame

\mainline{1.e4 \skakcom{Great move.} e5}  % this fails

\skakcom{Another great move.}  % this works

\end{document}
```

Putting the comment inside the mainline causes an error though it works outside the mainline.

Why is this and is there a way to make the alias?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add the tag chess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code tests for the actual string. This is hard coded. You can patch it, but then the original `\xskakcomment` will no longer work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\let\skakcom=\xskakcomment
\makeatletter
\def\xskak@test@comment#1=\skakcom#2=={%
       \def\@tempa{#1}%
       \ifx\@tempa\@empty%#1 beginnt mit \xskakcomment
        \setboolean{xskakboolcomment}{true}%
       \else
        \setboolean{xskakboolcomment}{false}%
       \fi}
\patchcmd\xskak@do@parsemainline{\xskakcomment}{\skakcom}{}{\fail}
\let\Mainline\xskak@do@parsemainline
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newchessgame

\mainline{1.e4 \skakcom{ Great move.} e5}  % this fails

\skakcom{Another great move.}  % this works

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Is there a reason for hardcoding the name?

Comment: The main code is from skak and I had to inject the additional test without breaking something.